# Call a windows .exe file from Python script with an argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, arguments, exe

Here is what i am trying to do ...

Download an exe from web
Install it silently
Run the downloaded exe and pass it an argument

The code I have is

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import subprocess
import os
from os import system

url = "https://downloads.com/App.exe"
output_file = "C:\\files\App.exe"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

# Silent Install
subprocess.call("C:\\files\App.exe /SILENT ")


system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\files\App.exe -ARG")
```

When i run it downloads the exe, installs the exe but then fails with this error when trying to exe the downloaded file

```
'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Comment: Post your actual code if you want us to diagnose it.

Comment: what do you mean ??????? I did!

Comment: Right. Then where does the `'C:/Program' is not recognized as an internal or external command` error come from if no such path exists in your code?

Comment: Or in other words, what line did the error occur on?

Comment: updated ... Last line

Comment: Dupe: [How do I execute a program from Python? os.system fails due to spaces in path](//stackoverflow.com/q/204017)

Comment: Legend ... Resolved .. will post in a sec

Answer (score 1):

Try to substitute:

`system("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\files\App.exe -ARG")`

by: 
`subprocess.call("C:\\Program Files (x86)\\files\App.exe -ARG")`

Answer (score 0):

Resolved using the below

```
import urllib.request
import shutil
import subprocess
import os
from os import system

url = "https://downloads.com/App.exe"
output_file = "C:\\files\App.exe"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response, open(output_file, 'wb') as out_file:
    shutil.copyfileobj(response, out_file)

# Silent Install
subprocess.call("C:\\files\App.exe /SILENT ")

subprocess.call(['C:\\Program Files (x86)\\files\App.exe', '-ARG'], shell=True)
```